# Get the list of the npm package versions belonging to the concrete dist-tag

Tags: npm

How to get the list of the npm package versions belonging to the concrete dist-tag.

For example, I'd wish to get the list of React versions that belong to dist-tag "experimental". Something like this:

```
npm view react versions --tag experimental
```

Comment: Do you mean something like this: `npm view react versions | grep experimental`? Which  on windows would be: `npm view react versions | findstr experimental`, Or something else?

Comment: @RobC Close but not enough. Your way assumes that the ending of the package version always matches the tag. The problem is that npm allows you to publish a package with version, for example, 1.0.0-beta, but specify the tag for it "alpha". In my case, few packages were published with wrong tags. I need to find them.

Comment: Do you mean something like what running `npm view react@16.12.0 dist-tags.experimental` does, but you want to check for every version of the package?

Comment: @RobC Yes. I'd like to get the list of all package versions relates to the specified tag.

Comment: npm doesn't provide a builtin feature to achieve your requirement. The `dist-tag` metadata is only available for each specific pkg version in the registry. You'll need to write your own program (_node.js_ or _Bash_) that essentially; **1)** Runs the `npm view <pkg_name> versions --json` command to get all versions. **2)** Iterates the Array returned from step 1. In each turn of the loop run; `npm view <pkg_name>@<pkg_version> dist-tags.experimental --json`. Currently there is 251 versions of react, unfortunately that means you'll need to do 252 separate `GET` requests to the npm registry.